# Allowing user to add text before printing in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, user-interface

Is it possible to allow the user to add some text at a specific position (yellow) within the Print Layout but without the user having to open the print layout?

I want to deploy that print layout on QField, but the user should have to possibility to add some own comments below the map canvas.

[image]

Comment: Of course yes. In case you want some help with this you must specify what's the exact case? Is it WMS printing or normal PrintLayout export from QGIS?

Comment: It is a normal Print Layout of QGIS. I need kind of a comment-field, where the user who wants to print can add some text.

Comment: So what keeps you from adding a text field at that place with default content like "add comment here if necessary, otherwise delete"

Comment: sorry for beeing not clear enough. I want it to be as easy and straight forward as possible - the end user should not need to edit the print form. Ideally, a pop-up would come and ask "Comments" and the user can just type whatever is needed. Planing to deploy it on QField, that's why editing the Printlayout per se is not possible

Comment: This modified the initial question substantially. You should always include all relevant details from the beginning and, where possible, include a sample project with dummy data. Like this you avoid fruitless attempts to solve a problem that is not what you want.

Answer (score 6):

*Updated answer, based on new information in question.*

You can add an attribute table for an existing map layer and choose to show only a certain field (for example, `"description"`).

1. Add the Attribute Table item

[image]

[image]

2. Choose which field(s) should be displayed

[image]

3. Apply an optional filter to show specific row(s)

[image]

Result:

[image]

Edits made to the attribute table will reflect in the Print Layout.

There are many more formatting options for the Attribute Table Item in the properties pane to style it exactly how you want.